# Proving that the $\chi^{2}$ Distribution is a PDF

Tags: integration, density-function, chi-squared

The $\chi^{2}$-distribution is given by $$f(x; k)\equiv \frac{1}{2^{\frac{k}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}x^{\frac{k}{2}- 1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}.$$

If the $\chi^{2}$-distribution is a probability-density function (PDF), then it must hold that $$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x; k) \, dx = 1. $$ However, when trying to prove this, I am stuck:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x;k) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{k}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}x^{\frac{k}{2}- 1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \, dx = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{k}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \, dx$$

Looking only at the last integral, we get: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx}_{= \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}$$

However, I am not yet sure on what to do with the first term. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The $\chi^2$ distribution only takes value in nonnegative reals.

Comment: Is there a reason for why this is so? For example, if we take $k = 2$, then $$\chi^{2}(x; k) = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{k}{2}}\Gamma(1)}x^{\frac{2}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \propto e^{-\frac{x}{2}},$$ which can for sure take negative values. :) After all, for the Gaussian distribution, we also don't restrict ourselves to positive values.

Comment: It is [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) of $\chi^2$-distribution that the support is $[0,\infty)$.  The "square" not without reasons.

Comment: Alright, good to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you don't integrate in $(\infty,0]$ since the chi squared distribution isn't defined there. You also have written

> $$\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}\color{red}{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}\mathrm{d}x}_{= \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}$$

Which is **wrong**. The integral definition of the Gamma function for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ is
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}\color{red}{e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x$$
The exponent should be $-x$, not $-x/2$. With a change of variable $t=x/2$ we can write
$$\int_0^\infty x^{k/2-1}e^{-x/2}\mathrm{d}x=2^{k/2}\int_0^\infty t^{k/2-1} e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t=2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral is

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k/2}x^{k/2-1}e^{-x/2}dx$$

Substituting

$$\frac{x}{2}=y$$

you get

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}y^{k/2-1}e^{-y}dy}_{=\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The **density of** the chi-square distribution is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{k/2} \Gamma(k/2)}x^{k/2- 1}e^{-x/2} & \text{for } x>0, \\[6pt]
0 & \text{for } x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
And so
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)\, dx + \int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \, dx = 0 + \int_0^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx.
$$

And then
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2} \left(\frac{dx} 2 \right) = \int_0^{+\infty} u^{k/2-1} e^{-u} \, du = \Gamma\left( \frac k2 \right).
$$